# How to best categorize a continuous variable that has many observations with the same value?

Tags: r, quantiles, continuous-data

I have an air pollution variable (PM2.5 measurements) for a dataset of 9,506 participants based on geographical location. Because many of the participants live in the same general area, there is a large proportion of observations with the same exact value for PM2.5. For example (biomeclean being my df and avgpm25 being the air pollution measure variable),

```
quantile(biomeclean$avgpm25)
```

returns

```
Average PM2.5 [ug/m3] 
       0%       25%       50%       75%      100% 
 4.562985  7.908445  9.464553  9.464553 10.275000
```

Similarly,

```
> summary(biomeclean$avgpm25)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  4.563   7.908   9.465   8.738   9.465  10.275
```

And trying to split it into smaller chunks gave me this:

```
> quantile(biomeclean$avgpm25, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/6))
Average PM2.5 [ug/m3] 
0% 16.66667% 33.33333%       50% 66.66667% 83.33333%      100% 4.562985  7.819733  7.908445  9.464553  9.464553  9.464553 10.275000
```

So you can see that a lot of participants have the same exact value of 9.464553 (basically because they live in a similar area as defined by my geographical variable).
Does anyone know of a better way to categorize this variable? I am keeping it continuous for my actual regression analyses later on, but it's much easier to visualize categories in my table. Should I create arbitrary cut points rather than ones based on the distribution of the variable?

Comment: What's the motive for further categorising at all? The spikes of repeated values are just what they are but they don't justify further coarsening of the data. Conversely, if there are say fewer than 20 distinct values, a table may be fine; otherwise, it won't help much.

Comment: Quantile plots can work well at showing spikes in a distribution ,as well as other features. See https://www.stata.com/meeting/uk16/slides/cox_uk16.pdf for examples (especially slides 23 and 52).

Comment: Perhaps conceiving of this as a continuous variable is unhelpful.  It sounds like you begin with a *sample* based on a spatial stochastic process (whose response likely is continuous), and have then *resampled* from this finite dataset.  The result is a *discrete* distribution for a variable whose *measurement type* has a continuous nature.  Use this insight to formulate a suitable probability model (which likely differs strongly from the model used for your regression procedure: in particular, the responses are *not* independent).

Comment: This might reasonably be considered a *mixed* variable, i.e. a mixture of a continuous and discrete distributions. For such distributions, as Nick Cox suggests, the quantile function is often more useful than a pdf or cdf.